# Convert a string to an array with a key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `string` like this:

```
<enq fiscal="no" lastcommanderror="no" intransaction="no" lasttransactioncorrect="yes" />
```

I want to convert the above string into an array, and the `output` has to be this:

```
array(
    ['fiskal'] => "no",
    ['lastcommanderror'] => "no",
    ['intransaction'] => "no",
    ['lasttransactioncorrect'] => "yes"
)
```

Comment: Your string looks like part of an XML document, so you should be able to use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SimpleXMLElement:

```
$xmlString = '<enq fiscal="no" lastcommanderror="no" intransaction="no" lasttransactioncorrect="yes" />';

$array = ((array)(new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString)))["@attributes"];

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make the string a json by replacing some characters then json_decode it.

```
$str = str_replace(['<enq ',  ' />', '=', ' '], ['{"', '}', '":', ',"'], $str);

$arr = json_decode($str, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$string = '<enq fiscal="no" lastcommanderror="no" intransaction="no" 
lasttransactioncorrect="yes" />';

// remove the <enq /> and whitespaces
$string = trim(ltrim(rtrim($string, '/>'), '<enq'));

$finalArray = [];
foreach (explode(' ', $string) as $value) {
    $elements = explode('=', $value);
    $finalArray[$elements[0]] = $elements[1];
}
```